# How to split string into an array

Tags: ruby, string, split

Here is my sample string with values.

Sample String:-

```
str = "2014-09-04 21:12:05" "5469687123030383463" "192.168.1.2" "4" "7879" "0" "43" "http://www.google.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36" "404" "123" "F" "21549" "50" "0" "-" "-" "Test1":"T" "Test2":"T" "Test3":"F" "Test4":"T" "Test5":"F" "Test6":"T" "Test7":"F"
```

If i split using space:-

```
Use str.split(' ')
```

Result is:-

```
["\"2014-09-04", "21:12:05\"", "\"5469687123030383463\"", "\"192.168.1.2\"", "\"4\"", "\"7879\"", "\"0\"", "\"43\"", "\"http://www.google.com\"", "\"Mozilla/5.0", "(X11;", "Linux", "x86_64)", "AppleWebKit/537.36", "(KHTML,", "like", "Gecko)", "Chrome/35.0.1916.153", "Safari/537.36\"", "\"404\"", "\"123\"", "\"F\"", "\"21549\"", "\"50\"", "\"0\"", "\"-\"", "\"-\"", "\"Test1\":\"T\"", "\"Test2\":\"T\"", "\"Test3\":\"F\"", "\"Test4\":\"T\"", "\"Test5\":\"F\"", "\"Test6\":\"T\"", "\"Test7\":\"F\""]
```

But i need like below:-

Expected result:-

```
["\"2014-09-04 21:12:05\"", "\"5469687123030383463\"", "\"192.168.1.2\"", "\"4\"", "\"7879\"", "\"0\"", "\"43\"", "\"http://www.google.com\"", "\"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36\"", "\"404\"", "\"123\"", "\"F\"", "\"21549\"", "\"50\"", "\"0\"", "\"-\"", "\"-\"", "\"Test1\":\"T\"", "\"Test2\":\"T\"", "\"Test3\":\"F\"", "\"Test4\":\"T\"", "\"Test5\":\"F\"", "\"Test6\":\"T\"", "\"Test7\":\"F\""]
```

How can i do in ruby to achieve the expected result.

Comment: You cannot have such string.

Comment: How do you do it, as a human? Write down the rules, then transform them to code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your string is:

```
str = '"2014-09-04 21:12:05" "5469687123030383463" "192.168.1.2" "4" "7879" "0" "43" "http://www.google.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36" "404" "123" "F" "21549" "50" "0" "-" "-" "Test1":"T" "Test2":"T" "Test3":"F" "Test4":"T" "Test5":"F" "Test6":"T" "Test7":"F"'
```

You can use a regular expression with a positive lookahead / lookbehind assertion to match a space that is surrounded by quotes (without capturing the quotes):

```
str.split(/(?<=") (?=")/)
#=> ["\"2014-09-04 21:12:05\"",
#    "\"5469687123030383463\"",
#    "\"192.168.1.2\"",
#    "\"4\"",
#    "\"7879\"",
#    "\"0\"",
#    "\"43\"",
#    "\"http://www.google.com\"",
#    "\"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36\"",
#    "\"404\"",
#    "\"123\"",
#    "\"F\"",
#    "\"21549\"",
#    "\"50\"",
#    "\"0\"",
#    "\"-\"",
#    "\"-\"",
#    "\"Test1\":\"T\"",
#    "\"Test2\":\"T\"",
#    "\"Test3\":\"F\"",
#    "\"Test4\":\"T\"",
#    "\"Test5\":\"F\"",
#    "\"Test6\":\"T\"",
#    "\"Test7\":\"F\""]
```

Comment: owww I didnt notice that the strings were in double quotes ... lol

Comment: @stefan if my string like this , then how i split into array of values.str = '"2014-09-04 21:12:05" 5469687123030383463 192.168.1.2 4 7879 0 43 "www.test.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36" 404 123 F 21549 50 0 - Test1

Comment: @karan that's a different task, please ask a separate question.

Comment: @Stefan I created ticket here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25720969/split-string-into-array-of-values