# Split String into array of values

Tags: ruby, string, split

Input String:-

```
str = '"2014-09-04 21:12:05" 5469687123030383463 192.168.1.2 4 7879 0 43 "www.test.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36" 404 123 F 21549 50 0 - Test1
```

When i split with whitespaces:-

```
str.split(' ')

 => ["\"2014-09-04", "21:12:05\"", "5469687123030383463", "192.168.1.2", "4", "7879", "0", "43", "\"www.test.com/\"", "\"Mozilla/5.0", "(X11;", "Linux", "x86_64)", "AppleWebKit/537.36", "(KHTML,", "like", "Gecko)", "Chrome/35.0.1916.153", "Safari/537.36\"", "404", "123", "F", "21549", "50", "0", "-", "Test1"]
```

Expected:-

```
str =  ["2014-09-04 21:12:05", "5469687123030383463", "192.168.1.2", "4", "7879", "0", "43", "www.test.com/", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36", "404", "123", "F", "21549", "50", "0", "-", "Test1"]
```

How can i achieve via ruby

Comment: So you need to split string on whitespaces?

Comment: Yes. But some values contains double quotes.

Comment: watch out split with whitespace result and expected result.It has differences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string looks so similar to UNIX shell arguments that I'd just use [Shellwords::shellsplit](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html). Note that this removes the quotes, but do you really need them?

```
require 'shellwords'
Shellwords::shellsplit(str)
#=> ["2014-09-04 21:12:05", "5469687123030383463", ..., "-", "Test1"]
```

Comment: i got what i expected using shellwords. Thanks.

Comment: Great! Maybe you should change the expected output in the question then. Note also that the URL does not match.

Answer (score 2):

You can cover both cases separately in your regex and join them with `|`:

```
str.scan(/"[^"]+"|[^ ]+/)
```

Comment: Wow. This is beautiful